# How to get all permissions for web service in android?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I have created an android application using `java, php(backend) and mysql(database)`. I have placed my backend `php` code and the database on `Linux` hosting server. My problem is that I can only read the data from the database, i.e., my application can fetch the data from the server, but it couldn't make any changes to the fetched data and also I get errors when I run using the server, but when I placed the database and code in local system  it works perfectly on the localhost, but when placed in server it can only read the data but not `insert, update or delete` the data. I have already given full privileges to the database in the server. Can anyone please help me regarding this aspect?
I think the server doesn't accept requests from outsider like mobile. So my question is

```
what do we need to do such that the server accepts requests from mobile side?
```

PS: I have given full privileges to the database in server and also I have added Internet permission in the android manifest file.

@Lie Ryan: As per your request, here is my code to connect to server:

```
 protected List<List<String>> callWebServer(String queryString, String statement){

    List<List<String>> stringList = null;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("query", queryString));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("statement", statement));

    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(WEB_SERVICE_URL);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost,responseHandler);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseBody);

        if(statement.equals(DB_SELECT_STATEMENT) || statement.equals(DB_INSERT_STATEMENT)){

            List<String> queryStrings = null;
            // parsing query 
            if(statement.equals(DB_SELECT_STATEMENT)){
                queryStrings = splitQuery(queryString);


            JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("output");

            if(jArray.length() > 0)
                stringList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String rowData = json_data.getString("rowData");
                if(rowData.equals("nothing")){
                //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No record found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{

                    JSONObject getClassNameObject = new JSONObject(rowData);
                    List<String> tempStringList = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for(String valueStr:queryStrings){
                        if(valueStr.contains(".")) valueStr = valueStr.split("\\.")[1];
                        tempStringList.add(getClassNameObject.getString(valueStr));
                    }

                    stringList.add(tempStringList);
                }
            }
            }else{
                JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("output");
                stringList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(0);

                stringList.add(getList("mn", json_data.getString("rowData")));

            }
        }

        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Event Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){

    }catch(Exception e){

        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection:"+e.toString());
    }
```

and the php code to handle the request is:

```
 <?php
include "connect.php";

if($_POST["statement"] == "select"){

    $booleanRow = true;
    // for select statements
    $db_output = mysql_query($_POST["query"]));
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($db_output, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $output[] = array('rowData'=>$row);
        $booleanRow = false;            
    }       

    if($booleanRow){
        $row = "nothing";
        $output[] = array('rowData'=>$row);
    }

    print(json_encode(array('output'=>$output)));
}else{

    // for insert, update and delete       
    mysql_query($_POST["query"]);   

    $row = mysql_insert_id();       
    $output[] = array('rowData'=>$row);
    print(json_encode(array('output'=>$output)));
}

 mysql_close($link);
  ?>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you trim down a small sample of the code you're using to handle the request on the server side, and the code you're using to make the request. Also, try checking the permission of the database user on the server side. One thing to keep in mind when writing a web service is that servers do not care about where a request came from as long as the format of the request matches what the server is expecting.

Comment: @LieRyan please check my question now. I can surely say that there is no problem in the code but there is something that is needed to be done with the server, but as per your request I posted my code.

Comment: thanks, now temporarily remove (comment out) the part of the code that parses the JSON string, instead simply print the `responseBody` (to logcat or to a textview on screen), and rerun. Is the response what you're expecting? Next, add a `print($_POST["statement"])` and `print($_POST["query"]);` just after the `include "connect.php";`. Does the statement and query string reaches the PHP script? If they do, then it's probably an error in the MySQL part; try sprinkling some `print(mysql_error());` around `mysql_query()` and `mysql_fetch_array()`

Comment: @LieRyan Oh...! I've checked each and everything, but thats not at all my problem. Just let me know whether you have handled such project before and if so where did you place your database and php code? Thanks

Comment: @LieRyan and for your kind info this code works when run through the localhost. If had problem with my code then it would not have worked in localhost, right?

Comment: @LieRyan my problem is i can only read the data but not insert, update or delete. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes you may have checked it, but **you haven't reported what you tried**, in particular if there's any output from mysql_error when doing insert, update, or delete. Next step after this is to use another client from another device, try using curl from your workstation to make the POST and see if it reports any problem, check the status code either a 200 OK or if it generates a 500 error, for example.

Comment: @LieRyan i know where the problem persists, but don't know how to solve it. So please help me. Just tell me how to get full access from server through mobile.

Comment: please post the full error message, e.g. `ERROR 1045: Access denied for user: 'root@localhost' (Using password: NO)`; you're not helping yourself by holding back information. And no, you may *think* you know where the problem is, but you don't. Your own understanding of the problem is confused; mysql does not care that the php script is serving a mobile client vs the php script is serving a local client; because as far as mysqld is concerned, it is serving to a php script. That means the problem is not on mysql permissions.

Comment: @LieRyan thank you very much for your support. You were absolutely right. But the thing was it was not showing up any sort of errors. so I thought that the problem would be from server. But now I knew where the mistake is, i.e., the mysql queries were changing to \' where ever special characters occurred and thus the error. And I'm extremely sorry for my behavior as didn't want to disclose the code as this is a company project. Anyways thanks again and man you are really a man of patience.

Answer (score 1):

To allow applications to open network sockets you need to set the 'android.permission.INTERNET' permission in your android manifest file (AndroidManifest.xml):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

For a list of more permissions see the [Manifest.Permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) class.

Comment: Oh...! I already added that file and I've already explained in the question that I can connect to database and fetch the data from the server but cannot insert, update or delete the data. So please improve your answer.